# Delete an element from a linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Trying to delete a particular element from a linked list

```
void delete(int num) {
        Node node = head;
        Node prev = null;
        if(head.data == num) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        while(node.next!=null) {
            prev= node;
            if(node.next.data==num) {
                node.next=node.next.next;
                node=prev;
            }
            node= node.next;
        }
        if(node.data == num) {
            prev.next = null;
        }
    }
```

error

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at hackerEarth.linkedList.delete(linkedList.java:44)
at hackerEarth.linkedList.main(linkedList.java:67)
```

line 44 is - while(node.next!=null)
line 67 is - delete(sc.nextInt());

Answer (score 0):

you are just checking for `node.next` and not checking `node` itself

```
node.next != null
```

---

Just take a look - below you are assigning

```
node.next = node.next.next;
```

no let us imagine that after this `node.next` is `null` - few lines beneath we have

```
node = node.next;
```

what does mean that now `node` is `null` what causes NPE in the line *44*

```
while(node.next != null) // NPE! trying to access 'next' of null
```

Comment: If the list is empty, error will occur in `if(head.data == num)`

Comment: He specified the problematic line

Comment: With his particular test data, and without test data in the question we don't know what that is. Doesn't mean that's the only NPE-capable flaw in the code.

Comment: yup that's true

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed function:

```java
void delete(int num) {
        Node node = head;
        Node dummy = new Node();//Creating a dummy starting node.
        Node prev = dummy;
        prev.next = node;

        while(node!=null) {
            if(node.data==num)
            {
                prev.next = node.next;//Removing current node.
                node.next = null;//Removing reference to the next node.
                break;//Exiting the loop
            }
            prev = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        dummy = null;
    }
```

Imagine the nodes to be boxes with one pointer to the next box. You have to make the previous node point to the next node, so that the current node is skipped. This removes the attachment to the previous node. Then you have to remove the attachment from the current node to the next node, so that it is not connected to the linked list in any way. This means that it is not used anywhere in the code, so Java automatically deletes it from memory to save space.

Comment: Why would a `delete` method allocate new memory? It's better to write a few more lines of code with `if` statements.

Comment: @Andreas The method won't allocate new memory, but it's generally a good habit to get rid of all connections if you're deleting from a linked list.

Comment: `new Node()` is allocation of new memory. I didn't say whether it was temporary or more persistent, but it certainly *is* allocation of new memory. --- Not sure what you mean by *"generally a good habit to get rid of all connections"*. Of course you *have to* get rid of all references to the node being removed. I just suggested that you should use `if` statements to accomplish that, not new memory.